# Determining if species point data is upstream or downstream of artificial fish passes using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, watershed, boundaries, rivers

I am working with ArcGIS Pro.

I am working on a project to determine how to prioritize restoration of artificial fish passes. I have been supplied with species point data, point data of the artificial fish passes and river polyline data. Now I need to determine whether the species points are located upstreams or downstream from the fish passes. Do anyone have any suggestions?

I've tried to create a utility network, but have not been able to get any results.

Comment: Which software are you working with? How well are the species points placed in relation to the river line? How are the river lines split?

Comment: Sorry, im working with ArcGIS pro and the species point, as well as the fish passes, are overlapping the river lines.  The river lines are split at each tributary.  Regards Dan

Comment: Usually conceptual questions are off topic here, since there is no single, final answer to most of them. Anyway, I'd join the fish pass IDs to the rivers, determine at which length of tributary the species data and the passes are situated and then compare the length along the river of the species data to the closest fish pass.

Comment: Couldn't you use the orientation of your lines starting from a fish pass to the end of said line and compare that to the general direction of your river? Alternatively, if you are provided with elevation data of the passes and the samples I'd use that.

Comment: So when does a fish species point stop being above a barrier and is then below  the next upstream barrier? Questions such as your without better description and images to show the distribution of your data are difficult to answer. Edit your question. Are for example your fish data assigned the ID of the barrier they are linked to?

Comment: Create a geometric network and use trace tools. Post specific problems and your attempts at fixing those problems when they arise.

Answer (score 0):

There's an app for that! I think using a combination of [SSN and STARS](https://www.fs.fed.us/rm/boise/AWAE/projects/SpatialStreamNetworks.shtml) is exactly what you are looking for. Partially ArcGIS based, more R based in the actual analysis. STARS (Spatial Analysis Tools for River Systems) is the ArcGIS toolset used to prepare the data for analysis in SSN (Spatial Stream Network), which is an R package for stream network analysis of primarily fisheries data.